# Passing object from objective c to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

I have webview which load from local html file. I am trying to pass array from objective c to javascript function and BTW I am new to javascript.

Below code is for load html file and to call function:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"javascript"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
[web_out loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login_info('%@')",arrlog];
[web_out stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

In my html file:

```
function login_info(arr){
    alert("arr:- " +arr);
}
```

Alert prints 'undefined'. So,how can i take value of arrlog to this javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
{
    NSString *value = [arrlog componentsJoinedByString:@"','"];
    [web_out stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"login_info(['%@'])", value]];
}
```

In html file:

```
function login_info(arr){
     alert("arr:- " +arr);
}
```

I was checking alert in browser but it displays only in simulator because function is calling from objective c side.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links and hope it will help.

http://www.steamclock.com/blog/2013/05/apple-objective-c-javascript-bridge/https://github.com/darionco/JavaScriptCore-iOS

Comment: link is not available

Comment: http://perrymitchell.net/article/communication-between-javascript-ios-using-uiwebview-base64/

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to check how to communicate with webview and objective c

http://perrymitchell.net/article/communication-between-javascript-ios-using-uiwebview-base64/